# "Valid CSRF Token Required" in Osticket After login?

Tags: php, osticket

My **osTicket Version 1.10** is installed in **PLESK Windows Server**. I have tried to install **XAMPP** on the **PLESK Windows Server** but not able to start **XAMPP** .

Soon I get error after login  to **osTicket** "*Valid CSRF Token Required in Osticket After login*" which was earlier working fine

After login I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

in `include/class.ostsession.php`

Just add this line:

```
$this->data->session_data = "";
```

After:

```
catch (DoesNotExist $e) {
        $this->data = new SessionData(['session_id' => $id]);
```

So it will be:

```
catch (DoesNotExist $e) {
        $this->data = new SessionData(['session_id' => $id]);
        $this->data->session_data = "";
```

Then try to login from scratch, don't just refresh the submission.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

My configuration

- Win 2012 R2 Standard (64bit)
- PHP 7.1.7 64bit (installed by Web Platform Installer)
- MySql 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20 (installed by MySql Installer Community Edition)
- osticket 1.10 (on IIS)

I had the same problem: "Valid CSRF Token Required..."

Here is where I found the fix:
https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/commit/424bfc99d93b920f6162b602eeea41125086425d

And here is a conversation about the problem:
https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/issues/3546

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. MySQL table 'ost_session' was broken. Run this command in MySQL:
`REPAIR TABLE ost_session`

Comment: Check your logs table in mysql (table name is ost_syslog I think). You should find a reason there. My log contains detailed info about SQL error with this line in it: 'Table './osticketdb/ost_session' is marked as crashed and should be repaired'. It hapened me three times over 16 months I am using Osticket.

Comment: For me this issue was resolved after downgrading the PHP version. Now I am using 5.6 and this issue is no more poping up. P.S. I was using PHP 7.1.1 before.

Comment: Had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PHP 7.1.1, then I changed to 7.0.15 and it worked

Comment: Hello, please add some explanation to your answer so it has more detail and easier to understand/follow.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after installing OST 1.10 on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 7 using PHP Manager for IIS. (http://osticket.com/wiki/Installation#Windows_Recommended_Links)
Accorinding to "To install osTicket, your web server must have PHP 5.3 (or better)" I installed "the latest PHP version" in my case 7.1.1. With PHP 7.1.1 I could not login into the SCP.
After changing the PHP Version from 7.1.1 to 5.4.45 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of varnish cache login credentials.

Test directly with web server host entries. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but what worked for me was to use another browser on my computer or clearing the cache

Answer (score 0):

Login to you server using `ssh(ssh username@ip)` and then check if in your Apache/Centos config file following setting is enabled using the below command

```
For Centos - nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
For Apache - nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then replace

> Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure

with

> #Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure

At last restart the web server.